# Android, How to add swipe gesture to show remaining text when text is too large for TextView

Tags: android

I'm looking to write an android book reader (I have looked at PageTurner, FBReaderj and cool reader but these don;t suit my needs as they are all full blown apps with lots of functionality that I do not wish to include in my app. Basically I just need a reader, not a library.

So I'm looking at using epublib combined with the html spanner util from page turner to implement my own reader. this combination works to get text from epubs into a text view very nicely apart from the fact that most of the time the text in the text view is larger than the text view itself. so I'm looking at how to implement a swipe option to show the next bit of text as a page.

I would appreciate any guidance on the best approach for this.

Comment: [This link here](https://github.com/psiegman/epublib/issues/18) might be what you are looking for. It shows how to split large amount of text into multiple pages.

Comment: @udiboy I think that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much, you have no idea how long I have been trying to do this! Please feel free to answer the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link here](https://github.com/psiegman/epublib/issues/18) might be what
you are looking for. It shows
how to split large amount of
text into multiple pages.

Then you can use whatever code you use to transition between pages.